# Why I didn't get results when adding Where clause to my query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm using Mysql JDBC driver.. but I have some problem..

the problem is when I use `SELECT` Query in java source code.

When I use this query:

```
select * from [name of table]
```

I've gotten result of query from DB successfully.

but when I use this query:

```
 select * from student where (substring(stu_name,0,1)>= '가' and substring(stu_name,0,1) < '나') ;
```

I've not gotten result of query from DB..

The difference thing is just that using `where` or not.

**What's the problem?**

**How can I solve this problem?**

this is my code below

this query isn't working

```
select * from student where (substring(stu_name,0,1)>= '가' and substring(stu_name,0,1) < '나') ;
```

this query is working very well

```
select * from student;
```

The difference thing is just only query information .. rest of the source code is the same absolutely

---

I added my java source code
public class Center {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql =  "select * from student where (substring(stu_name,0,1)>= '가' and substring(stu_name,0,1) < '나') ";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String id = "root";
    String password = "jsyun0415";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement prepareState = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list_second = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load JDBC driver..");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, password);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(rs.getNString("stu_no"));
                list_second.add(rs.getNString("stu_ename"));
            }

        //test = list.get(2);
    } catch (SQLException sqex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + sqex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + sqex.getSQLState());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: what is your datatype for `stu_no`?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: May be very obvious, but does that query ( `select * from student where stu_no = 20001001` ) return something when executed in a database tool like MySQL Workbench?

Comment: You will need to share your Java code not just the queries

Comment: that's right!! when I executed in a database tool workbench It was worked well

Comment: Oww, on-ASCII in Java code.  Now we really need to see your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer suggests that there's no problem with the Java code; it's your data.

Can you run the query in the MySQL admin tool and get back a result set that's not empty?  If yes, there's a problem with your Java code.  There must be an error that you either aren't supplying or you swallow with an empty catch block.

Do you get an error message or stack trace, or is the result set empty?  If it's the latter, perhaps there is no student row with number 20001001.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the the character encoding in the JDBC connection URL:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
```

Otherwise the character encoding between client and server is automatically detected upon connection, this means that the Korean text in your query will be wrongly encoded and will probably cause the query to return zero results.
You can read more about this in the MySQL JDBC driver documentation - [Using Character Sets and Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL function "substring" parameter 0 is wrong, only more then zero allowed.